# Why is the last char being cut from the string?

Tags: c, arrays, char

Why is the last char being cut from the string below?

```
char *data[10];
char napis[] = "Witam";

data[0] = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * strlen(napis+1));

strncpy(data[0], napis, strlen(napis+1));
data[0][strlen(napis+1)] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", data[0]);
```

It seems that everything should be OK, but the program returns one character less (last).

Return "Wita" instead "Witam".

Comment: There is another strange thing in your code besides the bug with improper placement of that `+1`. For some reason you used `strncpy` function, which is not really intended to be used for copying zero-terminated strings. You asked it to copy `strlen(napis)+1` characters. In fact, `strncpy` will stop at the last `\0` in the source string (i.e. it will copy only `strlen(napis)` characters) and then fill the rest of the target buffer with zeroes. The end result is, of course, correct, but using `strncpy` for this purpose is a rather weird thing to do. Why didn't you just use `strcpy`?

Comment: Since you know exactly how many characters you have to copy, even `memcpy` would have been a better choice. But `strncpy`???

Comment: Note also that your `data[strlen(napis)+1] = '\0';` is a major error. It writes beyond the array boundary (this error still exists in the accepted answer as well). In fact, you don't need it at all, since in this specific case `strncpy` will correctly terminate the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By `strlen(napis+1)` you do a pointer increment so you calculating the length of the chararray 'itam\0'.

To add 1 to the length of the char it would be correct to execute `strlen(napis)+1`.

```
char *data[10];
char napis[] = "Witam";

data[0] = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * (strlen(napis)+1));

strncpy(data[0], napis, strlen(napis)+1);
data[strlen(napis)+1] = '\0';

printf("%s\n", data[0]);
```

Comment: This `data[strlen(napis)+1] = '\0';` is actually wrong. You are writung beyond the end of the array. Actually, the `data[strlen(napis)+1] = '\0';` is completely unnecessary. The `strncpy` is guaranteed to add the proper zero terminator in this specific case. But in general case using `strncpy` for zero-terminated string copying is an abuse of function that exists for completely different purposes.